# How to change JSON structure on pyspark?

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka

I have two json files that are read by kafka and this is their printSchema ()

JSON1 printSchema:

```
root
 |-- _id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Data: string (nullable = true)
 |-- NomeAzienda: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Valori_Di_Borsa: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- PrezzoUltimoContratto: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Var%: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- VarAssoluta: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- OraUltimoContratto: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- QuantitaUltimo: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- QuantitaAcquisto: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- QuantitaVendita: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- QuantitaTotale: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- NumeroContratti: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- MaxOggi: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- MinOggi: double (nullable = true)
```

JSON2 printSchema():

```
root
 |-- _id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- News: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- TitoloNews: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- TestoNews: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- DataNews: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- OraNews: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- SoggettoNews: string (nullable = true)
```

Joining the two JSON I get this printSchema():

```
root
 |-- _id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Data: string (nullable = true)
 |-- NomeAzienda: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Valori_Di_Borsa: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- PrezzoUltimoContratto: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Var%: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- VarAssoluta: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- OraUltimoContratto: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- QuantitaUltimo: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- QuantitaAcquisto: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- QuantitaVendita: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- QuantitaTotale: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- NumeroContratti: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- MaxOggi: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- MinOggi: double (nullable = true)
 |-- _id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- News: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- TitoloNews: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- TestoNews: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- DataNews: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- OraNews: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- SoggettoNews: string (nullable = true)
```

But the result I would like to have is this:

Update Root:

```
 -- _id: string (nullable = true)
 -- Data: string (nullable = true)
 -- NomeAzienda: string (nullable = true)
 -- Valori_Di_Borsa: struct (nullable = false)
     |-- PrezzoUltimoContratto: double (nullable = true)
     |-- Var%: double (nullable = true)
     |-- VarAssoluta: double (nullable = true)
     |-- OraUltimoContratto: string (nullable = true)
     |-- QuantitaUltimo: double (nullable = true)
     |-- QuantitaAcquisto: double (nullable = true)
     |-- QuantitaVendita: double (nullable = true)
     |-- QuantitaTotale: double (nullable = true)
     |-- NumeroContratti: double (nullable = true)
     |-- MaxOggi: double (nullable = true)
     |-- MinOggi: double (nullable = true)
     |-- News: struct (nullable = false)
                |-- id: string (nullable = true)
                |-- TitoloNews: string (nullable = true)
                |-- TestoNews: string (nullable = true)
                |-- DataNews: string (nullable = true)
                |-- OraNews: long (nullable = true)
                |-- SoggettoNews: string (nullable = true)
```

How can I do it using pyspark?

This is my code:

```
   df_borsa = spark.readStream.format("kafka") \
                  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafka_broker) \
                  .option("startingOffsets", "latest") \
                  .option("subscribe","Be_borsa") \
                  .load() \
                  .selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)") 

   df_news = spark.readStream.format("kafka") \
                  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafka_broker) \
                  .option("startingOffsets", "latest") \
                  .option("subscribe","Ita_news") \
                  .load() \
                  .selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)") 

    df_borsa =df_borsa.withColumn("Valori_Di_Borsa",F.struct(F.col("PrezzoUltimoContratto"),F.col("Var%"),F.col("VarAssoluta"),F.col("OraUltimoContratto"),F.col("QuantitaUltimo"),F.col("QuantitaAcquisto"),F.col("QuantitaVendita"),F.col("QuantitaTotale"),F.col("NumeroContratti"),F.col("MaxOggi"),F.col("MinOggi")))

    df_borsa.printSchema()

    df_news = df_news.withColumn("News",F.struct(F.col("TitoloNews"),F.col("TestoNews"),F.col("DataNews"),F.col("OraNews"),F.col("SoggettoNews")))

    df_news.printSchema()

    df_join = df_borsa.join(df_news)

    df_join.printSchema()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check below code.

Extract struct `Valori_Di_Borsa` column, add `News` column & reconstruct struct back.

```
df_join = df_borsa.join(df_news)
.withColumn("Valori_Di_Borsa",F.struct(F.col("Valori_Di_Borsa.*"),F.col("News"))))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But it gives me this error:

TypeError: _ () takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: Thank you very much! I inserted a ")" in F.col ("Valori_Di_Borsa. *"), F.col ("News") and now it works!